# $\log$ concavity of $f(x)*g(x)$ when $\log[f(x)]$ is concave over $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ and $g(x)$ is log-concave over $(a,d)$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, convex-analysis

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_concave_function#Operations_preserving_log-concavity) says that $log-concavity$ is closed under products.

I am wondering how this translates to a function that is log concave over intervals but maybe not over the union of intervals.

> My guess is that $f(x)g(x)$ would be log-concave over the respective
>   integrals, but not over the union of the intervals as well.
>    - **is this correct?**

---

My reasoning for this is that we could just apply the fact that log-concavity is closed under products to each of the intervals individually?(by intervals I mean the intervals where $Log(f(x))$ is concave)
 - the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_concave_function#Operations_preserving_log-concavity) doesn't say anything about the domains though, so I'm not 100% sure I'm correct about this.
  - (although I guess the proof using the fact that the log of the product is the sum of the logs should hold over each domain, so my question is probably trivial)

Comment: As long as these intervals are the same for both $f$ and $g$, then yes, you will get log-concavity for each interval separately. That does not mean that $f(x)g(x)$ will be log-concave over the real line.

Comment: @EuxhenH Even if the intervals are not the same, if the overlap we would get log-concavity over the overlapping sections, wouldn't we? i.e. if $f$ is log concave over $(0,2)$ and $g$ is log concave over $(1,3)$, the $f*g$ would be log concave over $(1,2)$?

Comment: Yes that is also correct.

Comment: @EuxhenH Thank you very much